# Perspective divide: Why use the w component?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

In OpenGL, I have read that a vertex should be represented by (x,y,z,w), where w = z. This is to enable perspective divide, whereby (x,y,z) are divided by w in order to determine their screen position due to the perspective effect. And if they were just divided by the original z value, then the z would be 1 everywhere.

My question is: Why do you need to divide the z component by w at all? Why can you not just divide the x and y components by z, such that the screen coordinates have the perspective effect applied, and then just used the original unmodified z component for depth testing? In this way, you would not have to use the w component at all....

Obviously I am missing something!

Comment: I think the Z axis also needs to be divided in order to do coordinate interpolation properly.

Comment: Because that is not how perspective transformation works. Maybe you should take a look at this: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Comment: you should read more materials about the subject -- `Transform`, e.g. chapter 4 of `OpenGLSuperBible'. as long as you understand the relationships  between those spaces and their corresponding transforms, you will have a clear idea of how the w component  works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

3D computer graphics is typically handled with [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) and in a [projective vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space). The math behind this is a bit more than "just divide by w".

Using 4D homogeneous vectors and 4x4 matrices has the nice advantage that all sorts of affine transformations (and this includes especially the translation, which also relies on w) and projective transforms can be represented by simple matrix multiplications.

> In OpenGL, I have read that a vertex should be represented by
>   (x, y, z, w), where w = z.

That is not true. A vertex should be represented by (x, y, z, w), where w is just w. In your typical case, the input w is actually 1, so it is usually not stored in the vertex data, but added on demand in the shaders etc.

Your typical projection matrix will set `w_clip = -z_eye`. But that is a different thing. This means that you just project along the `-z` direction in eye space. You could also put `w_clip=2 *x_eye -3*y_eye + 4 * z_eye` there, and your axis of projection would have the direction (2, -3, 4, 0).

> My question is: Why do you need to divide the z component by w at all? Why can you not just divide the x and y components by z, such that the screen coordinates have the perspective effect applied, and then just used the original unmodified z component for depth testing?

Conceptually, the space is distorted along all 3 dimensions, not just in x and y. Furthermore, in the beginning, GPUs had just 16 bit or 24 bit *integer* precision for the depth buffer. In such a scenario, you definitively want to have a denser representation near the camera, and a sparse one far away.

Nowadays, with programmable vertex shaders and floating-point depth buffer formats, you can basically just store the `z_eye` value in the depth buffer, and use this for depth testing. However, this is typically referred to as [W buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#W-buffer), because the (clip space) w component is used.

There is another conceptional issue if you would divide by z: you wouldn't be able to use an orthogonal projection, you always would force some kind of perspective. Now one might argue that the division by z doesn't have to happen automatically, but one could apply it when needed in the vertex shader. But this won't work either. You must not apply the perspective divide in the vertex shader, because that would project points which lie behind the camera in front of the camera. As the vertex shader does not work on whole primitives, this would completely screw up any primitive there if at least one vertex lies behind the camera and another one lies in front of it. To deal with that situation, the clipping has to be applied before the divide - hence the name *clip space*.

> In this way, you would not have to use the w component at all.

That is also not true. The w component is further used down the pipeline. It is essential for perspective-correct attribute interpolation.