# How to clip a vertex that is behind the camera?

Tags: graphics, 3d, camera, transformation, clipping

While developing a 3D renderer, I came across this issue. From what I read, clipping would normally be done like this with a canonical view:

My understanding of canonical view clipping

[image: 1]

However, if the vertex is behind the view frustum like this:

Vertex behind camera

[image: 2]

The canonical view volume transformation will put that vertex out in a non-sensical location.

To clip this triangle, I can only think of solving its intersection with the view frustum. Is there a way to do it with the canonical view volume?

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this myself today.

As per ...:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31687061/580677
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/158859/111157
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/65798/111157

.. clipping is (and *must* be) performed before the perspective divide.

Quoting the salient:

> You must not apply the perspective divide in the vertex shader, because that would project points which lie behind the camera in front of the camera. As the vertex shader does not work on whole primitives, this would completely screw up any primitive there if at least one vertex lies behind the camera and another one lies in front of it. To deal with that situation, the clipping has to be applied before the divide - hence the name clip space.

To me, this kind of makes sense, in that if clipping was done after the perspective divide (aka dehomogenization / divide by w), then clip space would be almost the same as NDC, which would make it redundant-ish. (I.e. why have clip space if there's a linear mapping from clip space to NDC?, you could just define clipping in terms of NDC and avoid the complexity of the unnecessary coordinate system of clip space.)

I don't fully understand clip space, but I found some other relevant resources that explain graphics pipeline clipping:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60911583/580677
- https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-5/